# Reading a formatted txt file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read the following text file using Java and populate the key value with the root name.

- A root eg(master) can contain n number of childs. A child eg(childA) can contain n number of sub childs.
- keyA and valueA comes under subchild_nameA and child_name and master_name.

### File content:

```
#comment
#comment
#comment

master master_name
  childA child_name
          subchild subchild_nameA
               data keyA valueA
               data keyB valueB
               data keyC valueC
          end
  end
  childB child_name
         subchild subchild_nameB
               data keyD valueD
               data keyE valueE
                   childC  child_name
                      data keyA valueA
                   end
               data keyF valueF
          end
end
```

Comment: I don't get the tag "JSF" here

Comment: actually, your text reminds me a lot XML.

Comment: maybe you could transform this format into XML, then you'd have lots of tools ready to use

Comment: how could i transform this into xml. can u suggest some ways to convert this into xml.

Comment: well, you know how xml looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have choice to go for XML then....
Create Parent_
  read for number of "tab" (/t) and put elements at child of parent. Use these recursively. Use Stack (LIFO) to get parents while adding.  You can create your algorithm.

Thanks, Anil